# Nulls enabled in cf2018 though Enable Null Support is turned off

Tags: coldfusion, null, coldfusion-2018

We're upgrading some of our applications from CF10 to CF2018.

On CF2018, we've unchecked 'Enable Null Support' in the ColdFusion Administrator, and we can see when we output the value of `enableNullSupport` that it is set to NO. However, but we're still seeing behaviour which suggests that Nulls are enabled.

e.g. When we create an object with a property (eg FirstName) which is not initialised, the expression `getFirstName() eq ""`,  which previously was true, is now `false` and `IsNull(getFirstName())` is true

The article on [Null support in ColdFusion 2018](https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2018/07/null-support-in-coldfusion-2018/) says:

> Now in your ColdFusion applications, you can assign null to a
>   variable, as shown below:
>
> ```
> <cfset price = null>
> ```

But if you try this line at https://cffiddle.org (with CF2018 selected), you get - *Variable NULL is undefined*.

It looks like the documentation around support for Null is misleading.

Comment: Try running code that should work if null is enabled. If that fails then there is likely some other change with components affecting you. Are you testing on the latest update for 2018?

Comment: thanks. I'm currently only able to test using a local docker-vagrant container (built from image eaps-docker-coldfusion.bintray.io/cf/coldfusion:latest).
There <cfset price = null> runs OK if Null Support is on, but otherwise gives 'Variable NULL is undefined'

Answer (score 2):

I contacted Adobe Support, who were able to replicate the issue, and came back to confirm that it was a bug.
They sent me a patch which has fixed the issue. The patch will be included in a future update to cf2018

Comment: So just to clarify, which issue(s) does the patch fix? Does the same apply to CF2016?

Comment: The main issue we had was that:  
when 'enable null support' was set off, for a property which hadn't been initialised, `getProperty() eq ""` returned FALSE.  
After installing Adobe's patch, the expression returns TRUE - so the issue has been fixed.  
I don't know if this applies to CF2016